# HTML 5 google publisher link validation error

Tags: html, validation, google-plus

HTML 5 google publisher link validation error:

```
    Error: Bad value publisher for attribute rel on element link: Not an absolute IRI. The string publisher is not a registered keyword or absolute URL.

From line 13, column 1; to line 13, column 75

</script>↩<link href="https://plus.google.com/my publisher id" rel="publisher"> ↩</he

Syntax of absolute IRI:
    An absolute URL. For example: http://example.org/hello, but not /hello. Spaces should be escaped as %20.
```

Comment: Looks like no one knows the solution to my problem here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you try this:

```
<link rel="author" href="https://plus.google.com/PUBLISERID?rel=publisher">
```

Passed HTML5 validation.

Comment: Wouldn't this conflict if you wanted to set the authorship to a profile and the rel=publisher to your Google+ company page?

Comment: The `rel="publisher` statement is not valid in the link tag for W3C. So if you want to put your G+ profile and your G+ page you should use `rel="author` in both. No matter if there are two.

Comment: Passing HTML validation shouldn't be the goal though. Having the right tag for Google to recognize is the goal.

Comment: This question is about HTML code validation, and thats the way. For your purpose, you can use: `<link rel="author" href="https://plus.google.com/PUBLISERID?rel=publisher" />` for the publisher and `<link rel="author" href="https://plus.google.com/PUBLISERID?rel=author" />` for the author. Anyelse, Google related the websites with the G+ Pages by the G+ button on the content of the website and the other tools https://developers.google.com/+/web/+1button/.

Comment: Thanks Albert, that makes sense, I didn't notice the `rel=publisher` in the query string!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using:

```
<link rel="author" href="https://plus.google.com/PUBLISERID?rel=publisher" />
```

Google can't find the publisher link!

Better solution is:

```
<a href="https://plus.google.com/PUBID?rel=publisher" rel="publisher">Google Page</a>
```

Passed HTML5 validation!